# Know who is the inheritor while debugging core dumps with GDB

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

My process has crashed, and I have a core dump.
I see that the process crashed while running a code similar to that :

```
class father
{
public:
  void virtual runVirtualFunc() = 0;
  void func()
  {
    runVirtualFunc();
    // ... crash here ...  THIS IS THE PLACE I NEED TO KNOW WHO IS THE INHERITOR (so I could analyze which "runVirtualFunc" ran).
  }
  virtual ~father() {}
};

class son1 : public father
{
public:
  void virtual runVirtualFunc() { /* do something 1*/} 
};

class son2 : public father
{
public:
  void virtual runVirtualFunc() { /* do something 2*/} 
};
```

I have a full call stack in the core dump, but I don't know who is the inheritor that runs the "func". Is there a way to figure it out (maybe by some pointer calculation tricks on `this` ? )

I don't have a live attached process, only core dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `info vtbl this` or just print `*this`. You will see the inheritor in output (`son1` in my example):

```
(gdb) info vtbl this 
vtable for 'father' @ 0x400920 (subobject @ 0x613c20):
[0]: 0x4007d8 <son1::runVirtualFunc()>
(gdb) p *this
$2 = {_vptr.father = 0x400920 <vtable for son1+16>}
(gdb)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me, `info vtbl this` gives me : "Undefined info command: "vtbl this".  Try "help info"."
And `p *this` gives me : "$19 = {<father> = {_vptr.father = 0x743b70}, <No data fields>}"

Comment: Did you build with debug info (with `-g`)? What is your gdb version?

Comment: My GDB version is : "GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)"

Comment: This: `$19 = {<father> = {_vptr.father = 0x743b70},...` most likely means that `this` is a dangling pointer which doesn't point into a valid object.

Comment: Also gdb 7.2 is rather old release. According to [NEWS](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=HEAD) file, `info vtbl` appeared in 7.5 release. I would try to upgrade to 7.5 or even better to the latest release. (I used 8.0 for my tests)

Comment: @EmployedRussian why does it mean what you said ?

Comment: @OopsUser "Why...?" GDB shows that `_vptr` points to location `0x743b70`, which is not inside a valid symbol (at least not one known to GDB). My experience tells me that the most likely way (though certainly not the only way) this happens is when `this` points into deleted object.